# w3c validation warning: Article lacks heading

Tags: html, w3c-validation

I have a page containing only the following HTML code:

```html
<article>
    <nav>
        <a href="test.html" rel="parent">Back</a>
    </nav>
    <header>
        <h2>Test</h2>
    </header>
    <p>Test</p>
</article>
```

Why do I get this warning when I try to [validate it](https://validator.w3.org)?

> **Warning**: Article lacks heading. Consider using `h2`-`h6` elements to [add identifying headings to all articles](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Usage/Headings/Missing).
>
> From line 10, column 2; to line 10, column 10
>
> `<body>↩↩↩`**`<article>`**`↩ <na`

Comment: The answer to your question lies in the link you posted

Comment: An `<article>` needs a `<h>`, there's nothing more we can tell you about it.

Comment: Is not `<h2>Test</h2>` enough?

Comment: It needs to be the first thing in the article tag. Your `<nav>` being first is the issue.

Comment: That's strange. The `<header>` element is a semantic element whose purpose is to explicitly declare… _a header_. I don't get who said that a `<nav>` element that precedes it makes the article lacking heading. Where is this written?

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that a sectioning content element (`nav` in your case) comes before the heading content element (`h2` in your case):

```html
<!-- A -->
<article>
  <nav></nav>
  <h2>Test</h2>
</article>
```

If you switch them, the validator doesn’t report a warning:

```html
<!-- B -->
<article>
  <h2>Test</h2>
  <nav></nav>
</article>
```

See the part of the document outline these snippets generate:

```
<!-- A -->

- article (no heading)
-- nav (no heading)
- "Test" (h2 of an implied section, on the same level as the article)
```

```
<!-- B -->

- "Test" (h2 of article)
-- nav (no heading)
```

#### Spec reference

[Creating an outline](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-html52-20171214/sections.html#creating-an-outline) describes the algorithm. I think the relevant step is this one (but I’m not used to reading such algorithms, so better take it with a grain of salt):

> **When entering a [sectioning content](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-html52-20171214/dom.html#sectioning-content-2) element**
>   Run these steps:
>
> 1. If `current outline owner` is not null, run these substeps:
>
>    1. If the `current section` has no heading, create an implied heading and let that be the heading for the `current section`.

As far as I understand, this is what happens with example "A":

1. The algorithm enters a sectioning content element (`article`).
2. **Before** it finds a heading (`h2`), it finds another sectioning content element (`nav`), and enters it immediately, so the quoted step applies.
3. The `article` is still the `current outline owner` and the `current section`, so the substeps apply (because `current outline owner` is not null).
4. As the `current section` (→ `article`) has no heading (it didn’t find the `h2` yet), an implied heading is created. So the `article` got a heading, but it’s not your `h2`.

---

I think the spec would ideally describe this also in the text ([I was surprised by this, too](https://github.com/hoyois/html5outliner/issues/7)).

Relevant post in the validator’s issue tracker: [Warning issued when headers are nested in an article](https://github.com/validator/validator/issues/103)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You are right. But I am really curious to see where this rule is defined in the specs. I suspect w3c validator added its own restrictions in this case. This rule doesn't make sense as it is, because a `<nav>` element is not part of the content, but of the meta-content. What would happen if instead of a `<nav>` I put there an `<aside>` element (i.e. something that I want be considered _a-side_ of the content flow, so that must be basically ignored)?

Comment: @TheWebIsTheOldBlack: I updated my answer with my interpretation of the algorithm (not sure if it’s correct, though). -- Regarding your second question: `aside` would make no difference here, it’s also a sectioning content element (there are four: `section`, `article`, `nav`, `aside`).